# get method that shows in the google and chrome url

Tags: google-chrome, get

Hi i just installed a chrome in my new development laptop and every time I go to google is does this weird URL from chrome into the url

```
https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=OG9OVP7YIOqS8QeN4oCwCQ&gws_rd=ssl
```

anybody knows what it is and why it is showing up on my development pc I already know its a Get method?
or maybe my pc just got infected with a trojan or virus?

I have never encountered it before is it a crawler or robot

what does it do and will it affect me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PC is not infected.
You must be accessing google.com using **http**://www.google.com, you just need to use **HTTPS** instead of **HTTP**.

When you access google.com using **HTTP** then google redirects you to **HTTPS** site for google and appends all the information that you are getting in your url.
Hope it helped.

[found the solution here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/5Toplm6lXPQ)